# Как в replaceAll проверить пустая ли группа?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Пишу программу на java. Осуществляю отображение введенных данных по маске.
Есть строчка с именем человека. В поле может быть Фамилия или Фамилия Имя Отчество (от 1 до 3 слов).

Маска выводит "Фамилия И." (Первое слово плюс первая буква второго слова плюс точка).

Для вывода использую `replaceAll("\\s*(\\S{0,20})\\S*\\s*(\\S)?.*","$1 $2.")`.

При нынешнем выводе, если в поле одно слово я получаю "Фамилия .". Можно ли как-то если в поле 1 слово, не выводить точку?

Нужно Чтобы

```
"Фамилия" -> "Фамилия"
"Фамилия Имя" -> "Фамилия И."
"Фамилия Имя Отчество" -> "Фамилия И."
```

Для реализации думаю нужно исправить второй аргумент функции "$1 $2." так чтобы точка выводилось только если есть второй аргумент. Знаете как это сделать?

Comment: Делите строчку сплитом вместо replaceAll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для пропуска однословных строк ваше регулярное выражение не должно их находить, используйте

```java
String result = text.replaceFirst("^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S).*", "$1 $2.");
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/PFE5mh/2).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(\S+)` - Подмаска №2: один и более непробельных символов
- `\s+` - один и более пробельных символов (`\h+` находит только горизонтальные пробелы)
- `(\S)` - Подмаска №2: один непробельный символ
- `.*` - осатльная часть строки.

Пример [работы кода в Java](https://ideone.com/ew1Bvs):

```java
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("Фамилия Имя Отчество", "Фамилия Имя", "Фамилия");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("^(\\S+)\\s+(\\S).*", "$1 $2."));
```

Результат:

```java
Фамилия И.
Фамилия И.
Фамилия
```

Если вам нужно оставить регулярное выражение без изменений, а изменить только замену, вам придётся использовать что-то вроде

```java
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("Фамилия Имя Отчество", "Фамилия Имя", "Фамилия");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\S{0,20})\\S*\\s*(\\S)?.*");
for (String str : strs) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    System.out.println(m.replaceAll(x -> x.group(1) + (x.group(2) == null ? "" : " " + x.group(2) + ".")) );
}
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/msyU8P).

Comment: Неподходит. В этом то и проблема. Если в поле будет "Фамилия" я получу "Фамилия .". А нужно "Фамилия"

Comment: @II **Подходит**. Если в поле будет `Фамилия`, вы [получите `Фамилия`](https://regex101.com/r/PFE5mh/2).

Comment: Тогда фильтр просто несработает, поэтому в ответе получаем то что было "Фамилия". По существу, еще есть ограничение на длину фамилии. В фильтре ее реализовать несожно, поэтому не описал. В голову приходит идея, как-то изменить "$1 $2.", чтобы получать нужный ответ. Вы знаете как?

Comment: @II Если вам нужен ответ с *вашим* исправленным кодом, приведите этот код в вопросе.

Comment: Так он и есть в вопросе. (\\S{0,20}) берет первые 20 символов

Comment: весь код чего? проекта или маски? Маска есть в описании replaceAll("\\s*(\\S{0,20})\\S*\\s*(\\S)?.*","$1 $2.")